SHA256 error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'crypto.subtle.digest') on mobile phone
Works fine on desktop but on the newest version of iphone on fully updated chrome or safari is giving this error
SHA256 error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'crypto.subtle.digest')

Is this just simply incompatible with mobile browsers? If so what is the native alternative for mobile chrome without using an external library?
I was thinking that the issue had to do with HTTPS/HTTP (testing in an HTTP LAN) but I'm wondering how https://github.com/Niek/obs-web gets around this as this works fine over HTTP on mobile.

to answer the first question, crypto.subtle.digest is compatible with browsers on the iphone (by which I mean Safari) since 2013

@Bravo so the undefined error is probably due to running HTTP even though it’s on the same LAN network. Which brings me to the second part how is the git I posted handling it so hashing works in an HTTP environment
